# Coldfusion ORM: Filtering and Limiting Data from Relational Tables

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I'm writing a report that pulls relational data from two tables in the same database via ORM. In my case, I have a groups table and a users table. I want to get all of the users in a certain group so I take a reference to the group entity I'm interested in and get the users in that group with call to one of ColdFusion's auto-generated getter methods (getUsers):

```
group.getUsers();
```

This returns an array of User entities. Great! That's exactly what I want.

My question is:

What have I really returned here? Is this an array of ALL of the users in this group? Or does this list have a default limit on it?

Bonus questions: If there is no limit, what if there are thousands (or hundreds of thousands) of users? Will that simply take longer to return? If there is a limit, can I set the limit myself or can I perform any other type of filtering on the returned array? How would one do that?

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW - when doing any kind of reporting, you will likely get better performance using plain old SQL to fetch the data you need. ORM is great, but there are times when it is not the best solution...for me...reporting is one of those.

Comment: I'm beginning to get that picture myself. This is my first experience with ORM and it hasn't exactly lived up to promises of making my development workflow faster. I can see the benefits for creating tables and for providing basic CRUD functionality but anything beyond the most basic of operations seems like a huge pain. 
Thanks, I appreciate the input.

Comment: Does the source code for the getUsers function not tell you what you have returned?

Comment: I'd didn't realize the source code was available to read - if so, that's not a bad thought. I can't seem to find it though - do you know the location?